# Protocol for a Bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: java, keyboard, bluetooth

How would a person go about making a Bluetooth keyboard in Java probably for Windows? I know Windows comes with some built in drivers but I have no idea how to talk with them.

Comment: Aren't keyboards made with plastic, metal, circuitry, etc.?

Comment: I'm using the android keyboard and Java to talk to Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what an android keyboard is but from what i understand, you want the android device to act as a keyboard for the PC.

If this is the case and you want to do this in java, use the [bluecove](http://bluecove.org/) library for windows and write a PC application in java that simulates keypresses.The application talks with your android device using the RFCOMM protocol supported by bluevcove.I'm assuming here that android APIs for bluetooth are available.

Comment: Is there a way to talk over Bluetooth and use native drivers? I was hoping to avoid having to develop separately for each OS

Comment: I'm not sure i understand you.AFAIK Bluetooth 'drivers' are low level code that drive the bluetooth hardware.As far as applications are concerned, they need to talk to each other using bluetooth 'profiles' that the bluetooth stack defines.

java and bluecove are platform independent, so where's the question of developing separately?

Comment: Ah, okay. I think I need some reading to do. I was under the impression that I would need a client/server setup, but I forgot about the profiles. Thanks for pointing this out!